# In acute $\triangle ABC$, show $DE+DF \leq BC$, where $D$, $E$, $F$ are the feet of the altitudes from $A$, $B$, $C$, respectively.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-transformation

> Let $\triangle ABC$ be an acute angled triangle. The feet of the altitudes from $A$, $B$, and $C$ are $D$, $E$, and $F$, respectively. Prove that 
>   $$DE+DF \leq BC$$ 
>   and determine the triangles for which equality holds.

(Note: The altitude from A is the line through A which is perpendicular to BC. The foot of this altitude is the point D where it meets BC. The other altitudes are similarly defined. )

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here typically frowns upon questions that are nothing more than isolated problem statements. **Help us help you.** Tell us what you know about the problem, and/or where you got stuck. (Put such information in the question itself, not in comments that may not get read.) This information helps answerers target their responses to your skill level and specific difficulty, without wasting anyone's time telling you things you already know. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the existence of the 9-point circle, the circumradius of the orthic triangle $DEF$ equals $\frac{R}{2}$.
Since the angles of the orthic triangle equal $\pi-2A,\pi-2B,\pi-2C$, your inequality is equivalent to
$$ \sin(2B)+\sin(2C)\leq 2\sin(A) $$
or to
$$ 2\sin(B)\cos(B)+2\sin(C)\cos(C)\leq 2\sin(B)\cos(C)+2\sin(C)\cos(B) $$
or to
$$ (\cos B-\cos C)(\sin B-\sin C) \leq 0 $$
which is trivial since over the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ the sine function is increasing and the cosine function is decreasing. Equality holds only for isosceles triangles.

Answer (score 4):

Let $F'$ be a reflection of $F$ across $BC$, so $FD = F'D$. Since $BC$ is diameter of circle around cyclic quadrilateral $BCEF$ and $\angle FDA = \angle EDA$ we see that $F'$ is on this circle and that $F',D,E$ are colinear. Since $BC$ is diameter we have $$BC\geq F'E = F'D+DE = FD+DE$$[image]

Comment: (+1) very elegant.

Comment: What is the reason for ∠FDA=∠EDA ?

Comment: Is it necessary to give a reason for F′,D,E are collinear?

Comment: For the first question, look at cyclic quadrilateral $BCEF$ and for the second, yes it is necesery, this means F'D,E are on one chord and it is less then diameter.